# Campo calculado SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

tengo la siguiente duda debo de realizar un campo calculado que me del el total de venta por linea, donde tengo precio x unidad (float), cantidad facturada(INT) y descuento(INT)

el tema esta cuando el descuento es = a 0 por que me tira error de división por 0

tengo esto pero no me funciona:

```
SELECT AVC.numseriefac ,
       AVC.numfac,
       Cast (AVC.fecha AS DATE)                           FECHA,
       AVC.codcliente,
       Substring(CL.nombrecomercial, 1, 40)               AS SUCURSAL,
       Substring(CL.nombrecliente, 1, 30)                 AS CLIENTE,
       AVL.descripcion,
       AVL.unidadestotal                                  AS 'UNIDADES',
      cast ((avl.dto / 100) as float)                      DESCUENTO,
       AVL.precioiva                                      AS 'PRECIO',
       Cast(( AVL.unidadestotal * AVL.PRECIO) as float) / IIF(AVL.DTO =0,1,100 * AVL.DTO)   TOTAL
FROM   albventalin AVL
       INNER JOIN albventacab AVC
               ON AVL.numserie = AVC.numserie
                  AND AVL.numalbaran = AVC.numalbaran
       INNER JOIN clientes CL
               ON AVC.codcliente = CL.codcliente
WHERE  AVC.numseriefac = 'SCAE'
```

En caso de que el campo descuento sea 0, nada mas deberia hacer el calculo precio x cantidad = total si el campo de descuento es <> a 0 entonces debería hacer el calculo (precio * cantidad) * (descuento / 100)

alguna sugerencia para poder calcular ese total con el descuento aplicado

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Por favor no uses imagenes, el codigo debe ir como texto. Y lo que tenes que comprobar es que no sea cero antes de dividir.. si es cero, que valor queres poner?

Comment: Hola gracias por las sugerencias las tomare en cuenta para futuros preguntas.
ok en caso de que el campo descuento sea 0, nada mas deberia hacer el calculo precio x cantidad = total si el campo de descuento es <> a 0 entonces debería hacer el calculo (precio * cantidad) * (descuento / 100)

Comment: nop.. no para futuras preguntas.. vos queres ayuda ahora, asi que tomate unos segundos en arreglar la pregunta para que puedan ayudarte.. usa el boton [edit] y arreglalo...

Comment: listo hermano, tenes toda la razon.. gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es necesario hacer la división, el total será Valor (Unidades * Precio) sumado al porcentaje del descuento aplicado al valor (Unidades * Precio) * AVL.DTO / 100

```
Cast((AVL.unidadestotal * AVL.PRECIO) as float) + Cast((AVL.unidadestotal * AVL.PRECIO) as float) * (AVL.DTO / 100)
```

De esta forma la sentencia quedaría

```
SELECT AVC.numseriefac ,
       AVC.numfac,
       Cast (AVC.fecha AS DATE)                           FECHA,
       AVC.codcliente,
       Substring(CL.nombrecomercial, 1, 40)               AS SUCURSAL,
       Substring(CL.nombrecliente, 1, 30)                 AS CLIENTE,
       AVL.descripcion,
       AVL.unidadestotal                                  AS 'UNIDADES',
      cast ((avl.dto / 100) as float)                      DESCUENTO,
       AVL.precioiva                                      AS 'PRECIO',
       Cast((AVL.unidadestotal * AVL.PRECIO) as float) + Cast((AVL.unidadestotal * AVL.PRECIO) as float) * (AVL.DTO / 100)
FROM   albventalin AVL
       INNER JOIN albventacab AVC
               ON AVL.numserie = AVC.numserie
                  AND AVL.numalbaran = AVC.numalbaran
       INNER JOIN clientes CL
               ON AVC.codcliente = CL.codcliente
WHERE  AVC.numseriefac = 'SCAE'
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Don Roger, la forma con la que detallaste la respuesta me funciono correctamente.

saludos